# Casperjs web service multithread

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using a CasperJS script as a web service, accessing it from a node server. What I did not manage to do is to make Casper be 'multithread'. If I make two simultaneously requests to Casper from postman the result will be something scrambled between both requests for one response, and the second will be null. I saw that PhantomJS has a page principle, but I did not find anything similar for Casper.

1. Can i call Casper's web service with multiple requests at the same time and get correct/coherent responses?
2. Is there some configuration needed for the web server to allow me to do this?
3. Should the request be done in a 'special manner'? Are there any caveats regarding this that i should be aware of?
4. If it can only function sequentially, would starting multiple servers on the same machine but different ports solve the issue?

Here is the casper web service i am talking about. When I make a request like
locahost:1338/?query=name.name it will crawl for that query on the
specified url. My problem comes when I make 2 parallel requests with different queries.

```
    //includes web server modules
    "use strict";
    var port = 1338;
    var server = require('webserver').create();
    var url = 'url to scrap';

    //start web server
    var service = server.listen(port, function(request, response) {
        var arr1 = [];
        var arr2 = [];
        var arr3 = [];

        var casper = require("casper").create({
              verbose: true,
              logLevel: 'error',
              pageSettings: {
                loadImages: false,
                loadPlugins: false,
                userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36'
              },
              clientScripts: ["vendor/jquery-1.12.1.js"]
        });

        casper.start(url, function() {
        }, function(){
            console.log(url + " not found");
            return;
        });

        casper.waitForSelector('.cssClass', function() {
        }, function(){
            console.log("not found");
            return;
        });

        casper.then(function() {
            var query = getQuery(request.url);
            casper.sendKeys('.cssClass', query);
            casper.click('.cssClass');

            casper.waitForSelector('.cssClass', function(){
                arr1 = this.evaluate(function(){
                    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".cssClass");
                    return Array.prototype.map.call(nodeList, function(node){
                        return node.textContent;
                    });
                });
            }, function(){
                console.log("not found");
                return;
            });

            casper.then(function(){
                if(names.length > 0)
                {

                    casper.waitForSelector('.cssClass', function(){
                        arr2 = this.evaluate(function(){
                            var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".cssClass");
                            return Array.prototype.map.call(nodeList, function(node){
                                return node.textContent;
                            });
                        });
                        console.log("found");
                    }, function(){
                        console.log("not found");
                        return;
                    });

                    casper.waitForSelector('.cssClass', function(){
                        arr3 = this.evaluate(function(){
                            var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".cssClass");
                            return Array.prototype.map.call(nodeList, function(node){
                                return node.src;
                            });
                        });
                        console.log("found");
                    }, function(){
                        console.log("not found");
                        return;
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        casper.run(function() {
            response.statusCode = 200;
            response.write(JSON.stringify({p1: arr1, p2: arr2, p3: arr3}));
            response.close();              
        });
    });

    console.log('\nServer running at http://localhost:' + port+'/');
```

Comment: Please provide code sample and formulaite your question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for not being clear from the first time.

Comment: I guess there are no answers because the questions are too theoretical and broad. `Can i call Casper's web service with multiple requests at the same time and get correct/coherent responses?` Probably. Why don't you try and check?

Comment: Why would I have posted here if I didn't already try and got stuck with this issue?

Comment: Then you should write extensively about that issue. `My problem comes when I make 2 parallel requests with different queries` What is the exact problem? How can we guess?

Comment: i think you may have that calling in multi request from the command-line instead of running inside the script.  :D CMIIW. @Vaviloff